# How to allow specific endpoint from specific host in spring boot oauth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

We have used the spring authentication server for providing my other spring boot application(Resource server). There are some endpoints that **do not need to get authenticated** for a **specific host**.

I have used the bellow code example but it works only without the OAuth server.

```
@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/url/**").permitAll().
```

anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(2)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/media/allVideos")
                        .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();   
    }
}
```

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Comment: Oauth2 server is disabled when adding the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I need both works together.